# Changing proxy account to run Scheduled SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

I have to update new account to run SQL  Server Agent job. This job is running under users account and his password will expire. That user no longer associated with company. I have created new login, I have also created new credentials. also mapped credentials with proxy account.

The issue here is when job executes on scheduled time. It is failing. I do not know the reason. The reason could be password protected ssis package.

I don't know the password. How can I update proxy account without failing schedule job?

I am using sql server 2008R2

Comment: **Error** Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x80070002 
"The system cannot find the file specified.". You may not be authorized to access this information. 
This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic565927-147-1.aspx